# javascriptのFileReaderAPIで画像を読み込んで、サーバにアップロードしたい

Tags: javascript

タイトルの通りなのですが、画像を読み込んでサーバにアップロードするまでは出来たのですが、
アップロードしたファイルを開こうとすると「ファイルが壊れています」と表示されてしまいます。
どなたかご教示いただけると幸いです。

HTML

```
    <ons-button ng-click="save()">ファイル選択 </ons-button>
```

JS（files[i]には画像ファイルのURIが入っています）

```
for (i=0; i<files.length; i++){
    window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(files[i], function(fileEntry){
        fileEntry.file(function(fileObj) {
            var file;
            var fileReader = new FileReader();
            fileReader.onload = function(e) {
                 file = fileReader.result;
                 Upload.upload({
                     url: URL,
                     data: {
                         file: file,entity: Upload.json({name: name})
                     }
                 })
            };
            fileReader.readAsBinaryString(fileObj);
        })
    });
}
```

FileReaderAPIを使わずにHTMLのinput type=fileでファイル選択してアップロードした場合は画像として開けます。
アップロード部分はng-file-uploadを利用しています。

追記：
質問がわかりにくくて申し訳ありません。
`<input type="file" name="file" onchange="save(this.files);" />

for (i=0; i<files.length; i++){var file = files[i];}`


と書いた時にfileに入るオブジェクトを、
「file:///data/data/(app id)/cache/aaa.jpg」というURIから生成したいのですが
どのようにすればよいでしょうか？という質問です。

追記2：
    [英語版の過去ログ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6850276/how-to-convert-dataurl-to-file-object-in-javascript)を参考に下記コードで自己解決しました。

```
var file;
var fileReader = new FileReader();
fileReader.onload = function(e) {
    var arr = fileReader.result.split(','), mime = arr[0].match(/:(.*?);/)[1],bstr = atob(arr[1]), n = bstr.length, u8arr = new Uint8Array(n);
    while(n--){u8arr[n] = bstr.charCodeAt(n);}
    file = new Blob([u8arr], {type:mime});
    // （アップロード処理）
};
fileReader.readAsDataURL(fileObj);
```

Comment: `ons-button`と言うことは`OnsenUI`ですか？`AngularJS`も使っていますか？、`Cordova`のような気がしますが、使用しているのは`monaca`ですか？関連タグを増やしてください。何のことに対して話しているのかいまいちつかめません。

Comment: 追記しました。タグを増やそうとすると「新しいタグ 'ng-file-upload fileapi' を作成するには、150 点以上の信用度が必要です。」と怒られてしまいました。

Comment: 質問が自己解決した場合はぜひ回答を作成して下さい。http://meta.ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/1747/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

コードは追記2に書いたとおりですが、Reader.resultを直接投げるのではなく
Uint8Arrayで取ってBlobを作成してやる必要がありました。